# Read NFC into browser

Tags: tags, keyboard, nfc, output

First of all I would like to thank everyone beforehand.

I want to know if it's possible to write a plain text to a NFC tag,
and make the reader read it to an application?

Basically write number 0000 to a tag - and every time they put the tag on the reader it'll put out the 0000 as text an application currently open (like a keyboard emulation).

Pretty much like a barcode scanner that outputs the barcode as normal keyboard input on any application currently open.

Sincerely,

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well guys, There is 1 RFID device that allows keyboard emulation (MOD-RFID125).
This allows me to make a login application based on RFID tags.